Цитату пишем с прописной буквы? (начало предложения)
...он лишь подмечает «Одно из забавных свойств человеческой природы», которое может привести к абсолютно разным...

Если цитата и в оригинале - начало предложения, причём представляющее собой законченную мысль (даже не будучи приведённой от начала до конца).
Иначе ни за что, просто несколько процитрованных слов:
...он лишь подмечает «одно из забавных свойств человеческой природы», которое может привести к абсолютно разным...

в этом случае со строчной, значит?

Да, со строчной.
